# Can there be more than one result of decoding a raw transaction?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

I was looking in `rpcrawtransaction.cpp` and came across the `signrawtransaction` rpc method. While reading through this method, I thought these lines seemed strange:

```
    vector<CTransaction> txVariants;
    while (!ssData.empty())
    {
        try {
            CTransaction tx;
            ssData >> tx;
            txVariants.push_back(tx);
        }
        catch (std::exception &e) {
            throw JSONRPCError(RPC_DESERIALIZATION_ERROR, "TX decode failed");
        }
    }
```

Why is a vector of transaction variants needed here? Could decoding a raw transaction ever have more than one solution?

Maybe this has something to do with unfinished transactions, specifically?

I noticed that `sendrawtransaction` doesn't have the same loop, but rather just has:

```
    CTransaction tx;

    // deserialize binary data stream
    try {
        ssData >> tx;
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        throw JSONRPCError(RPC_DESERIALIZATION_ERROR, "TX decode failed");
    }
```

The below seems relevant, too. It happens near the end of `signrawtransaction`.

```
    // ... and merge in other signatures:
    BOOST_FOREACH(const CTransaction& txv, txVariants)
    {
        txin.scriptSig = CombineSignatures(prevPubKey, mergedTx, i, txin.scriptSig, txv.vin[i].scriptSig);
    }
```

Maybe this has something to do with multisig?

Answer (score -2):

> Could decoding a raw transaction ever have more than one solution?

Decoding raw transaction is just a human-readable representation of transaction data. So, the answer is "no" and "yes"

There is only one decoding for transaction.

But another client/version may add some other fields for json

Comment: This doesn't explain the code I posted.